# Is it possible to run or use the GIMP CLI from a Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, gimp

I know that GIMP and a lot of it's plugins can be run from a command line interface. I am wondering if it is possible to run GIMP processing from a node server. If not directly, maybe indirectly (two servers- one for GIMP and one for the Node environment)?

Comment: There are different ways how to execute native commands from nodejs. Here's a good post about this: https://www.sohamkamani.com/nodejs/executing-shell-commands/

Comment: @Fred, thanks for the reply. I guess another thing I am wondering is how GIMP comes into play here. If I have a Node.js server, I definitely need to install GIMP somewhere. Would that mean I would need to use a Virtual Machine running Windows for instance, and install both GIMP and Node on it, and use that as a server or something?

Comment: node.js would need to be able to execute the gimp cli. that means gimp cli would need to be installed where node.js is.

Comment: @connected_user: The easiest way would be to install it on the same machine where you execute your NodeJS code. But are you sure that you need GIMP? Libraries like ImageMagick are designed to work from the CLI and might cover your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you can start a process from node.js, then you can run the Gimp CLI.

However,

1. Why use a Windows VM to run Gimp, which is written on and for Linux?

2. Why use Gimp? Most headless uses of Gimp I see could be done a lot more simply using ImageMagick in most cases, and for some more difficult cases using the GEGL CLI (GEGL is Gimp's graphic engine).

So before wondering about the tool, what is the required processing?